# Dividir tipo Long da resultado double incorrecto?

Tags: java, double, division

Por qué devuelve 2.0 en vez de 2.5? En qué momento pierde precisión?

```
    System.out.println(divide(50L, 20L));

}

public static double divide(long a, long b) {
    return ((double)(a / b));
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prueba de ésta manera.

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(divide(50L, 20L));


}
public static double divide(long a, long b) {
    return  ((double) a / b);
}
```

Entiendo que de la manera que lo estas realiando la división entre a/b retorna ya un entero, entonces al realizar el cast a (double) ya lo éstas realizando sobre un valor ententero.

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    long division = divide(50L, 20L);
    System.out.println("Division ---> " + division);
    System.out.println("Casteando a double ---> " + (double) division);

}
public static long divide(long a, long b) {
    return  a / b;
}
```

También puedes realizar lo siguiente utilizando la clase Long

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Double division = divide(50L, 20L);
    System.out.println("Division ---> " + division);

}
public static Double divide(Long a, Long b) {
    return  a.doubleValue() / b.doubleValue();
}
```

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta.